# Find triangle with given orthocenter and an apex on a circle

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, circles

We are given $k(O; r)$, $A \in k$ and $H : OH>r$. Find points $B$ and $C$ ($B, C\in k$) such that $H$ will be the orthocenter of $\triangle ABC$.
[image]
I am trying to see what is the point $F$ ($AH \cap k = F$), but I can't figure it out. Also $AH\bot BC$ but I don't know how to continue. I will be very grateful if you help me.

> Reversed: [image]

Comment: The question (except the added diagram) says nothing about F.  It is just a distraction.

Comment: Yes, I see that but I am wondering how to find B, C.

Comment: Do it the other way round. Draw an obtuse  triangle ABC with $\angle ABC \gt 90^0$. Form the orthocenter, H. Draw the circle circium-scribing $\triangle ABC$.

Comment: It is just a suggestion. We need to know all the related facts from the actual figure. Hopefully we can find the required solution by reversing the thinking process.

Comment: @Mick, I think that $B$ and $C$ lie on perpendicular bisector of FH but I don't know how to show it. Isn't that so? [Reverse](https://i.imgur.com/nNPKK08.png)

Comment: I'm trying to show that $\triangle FEC \cong \triangle EHC$ because they share $EC$ and are right-angled. I should proof that $FC=HC$ or $\angle FCE = \angle HCE$ or $\angle EFC = \angle EHC$ but I can't figure it out.

Comment: 1) If H is the ortho-center of $\triangle ABC$ (with B being obtuse), then B is also the orthocenter of $\triangle AHC$. 2) If you also draw the other two altitudes (HX on AC and AY on HC, then $EXY$ forms the so-called orthic triangle in which CBE is the ***angle bisector*** of $\angle XEY$.

Comment: @Mick, I don't understand fully. Now we have $\angle XEC = \angle YEC$?

Comment: @Mick, what did I miss?

Comment: $\angle XEC = \angle YEC$ is correct because that is the properties of an orthic triangle. Also, You are correct that  CBE is also the ***perpendicular bisector of FH***. I cannot show my pictorial proof in the comment. I will add that in the solution section.

Comment: @Mick, Okay I'm looking forward to seeing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added: Since $\angle AEC = \angle AYC = 90^0$, AEYC is cyclic. Hence, we have the added dotted circle. From that, $\angle 1= \angle 3$.

[image]

After that, E can be found. Hence, C is located. B......

Comment: I understood that $\angle FAB = \angle FCB$ but what happened next? Why do you have another circle?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova See added.

Comment: $\angle 1 = \angle 3 = \frac {\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{EY}}{2}$ and $\angle 1 = \angle 2 = \frac {\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{FB}}{2}$, thus $\angle 3 = \angle 2$. Right?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova ∠1 = ∠3 and ∠1 = ∠2, thus ∠3 = ∠2 directly.

Comment: Thank you! I think my way is also correct (inscribed angles). My last question is when we can state that a quadrilateral is cyclic? I haven't studied it yet, but I read some articles and still can't understand it. You've written $\angle AEC = \angle AYC = 90^\circ$...?

Comment: @NikolDimitrova Sorry to say that you way is NOT correct. We need $\angle 3 = \angle 2$ to prove the $\triangle CFE \cong \triangle CHE$. Once we have done that, we can then say FE = HE. That equality guarantees CE is the perpendicular bisector of  FH. To answer your question, the theorem that I quoted is called "the converse of angles in the same segment" which is one of the ways to prove a quadrilateral is cyclic.

Comment: I still don't understand why my way isn't correct. $\angle EAY = \angle ECY = \frac {\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{EY}}{2}$, $\angle FAB = \angle EAY = \angle FCB = \angle FCE = \frac {\newcommand{arc}[1]{\stackrel{\Large\frown}{#1}}\arc{FB}}{2}$, thus $\angle 3 = \angle 2$.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova The logic is incorrect. In the beginning, ARC FB is NOT equal to ARC BD yet. They will be equal only after we have proven $\angle 2 = \angle 3$. Out.

Comment: But you DO NOT need these arcs. Look at the angles. They're inscribed and are equal. We are looking at both circles and use the equal inscribed angles. Just see what I've written.